# Showing users who visited their profile is bad?

Tags: facebook, tracking, website-features

I have been thinking of implementing this feature to my website (not a dating website), but I did some research why Facebook does not use this function and I am very surprised.

It seems like a lot of people would like to see who visited their profiles.

So why is Facebook so afraid of this function and is it actually a good feature to enable users to somehow unlock this functionality (by unlock I meant for example if the user is registered 5 months you get this privilege or something like that).

Would it be harmful for the functionality of entire website to have this feature if people only would be able to see who has visited their profile without sharing this information?

Any cons and pros why it would be good or bad to have this feature?

Answer (score 1):

The user may feel this as a violation of privacy if the person they are visiting (whatever the purpose may be) know that their profile is being checked out by this user.

It is a good way to keep stalkers in their line with this feature.

But isn't this why Orkut got boring? It depends on the functionality of the site too. You can find this feature on LinkedIn and people do not mind it as LinkedIn is meant for a professional profile. Hence if my profile is visited by some recruiter or a peer, it means something other than stalking. At the same time sites like Facebook and Orkut are meant for a user's personal space. You go to those sites to tell people what you do in your free time, share images of your vacation etc. So if I get notification that some xyz has visited my profile when I actually want to be a person available only to my friends, it may or may not be taken positively by me.

So it depends on what your site is all about.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion here. Well I partly agree. You could make this future available only for your friends, which means you can only see if a friend visited. Other thing is, stalkers and people who might be interesting in talking to you (but to shy to add etc) are visiting your profile anyway, but you do not know that.

Comment: Facebook had a nice way to allow this. if a non-friend poked you and you poked back, then they could view your profile like a friend could. I don't know if they still have this feature online, but that is a subtle way to introduce people. 
You could let users see which of their friends visited their profiles and for non-friends, you could add an option like _converse_ and allow them to see certain details and start a convo. Then if that goes well they could become friends.

Comment: Like I said I am planning on making this function achievable via users inviting friends to the community. So if the user is not interested in this they will chose not to do that. Or even after you unlock that achievement, you could chose if you want to use it or not. But thanks for your points here, It helps me for sure

Comment: I am glad it helped. And yea, you could actually make it an option under privacy setting. Call it trail or something like that. _Let users know you visited their profile_ .

Comment: So as I understand is more like users will not want other people to see them going to their profile, but they would like themselves to see who visited theirs?

Comment: That could be the case. So if I enable that setting, when I visit your profile, it will show on your next login that I visited you. You can break it into two options. One to let the user know that you visited if that person is your friend, and another for a non-friend profile visit.

Answer (score 0):

If Facebook ever make it impossible to stalk without warning the stalkees, I bet alot of people stop using Facebook.

It is a function who do more harm than good imo